# Получение данных контрактов без подключения проекта сервера

Tags: c#, сервер, wcf

Имеется проект клиента.
Имеется проект сервера.

На сервере реализован контракт передаваемых данных.

**Вопрос:** Как получить интерфейс контрактов, запросов к серверу без подключения проекта сервера, как зависимость?

Топология проектов:

**Client:**

- ConnectionToServer

**Server:**

- GUI/..
- ConnectionProcess/..
- - DataContracts/..
- - IService.cs
- - Service.cs

Comment: Я ваше описание структуры проектов не понял, даже не понимаю самый простой вопрос - сколько у вас солюшенов. Один?

Comment: Вообще же, обычно делается отдельный проект DataContracts, который подключается и к серверу в зависимости и в клиент как зависимость. Это самый простой случай. Более сложный - когда у вас контракты собираются на сборочном сервере как отдельный Nuget-пакет и подключаются везде-куда-надо.

Comment: @AK, сейчас 2 проекта в 1 солюшене

Comment: @AK, проблема в том, что не знаю, как не подключать содержимое сервиса сервера, а подключить только его интерфейс.

Если создавать отдельный проект - это подходящий вариант, но остаётся только проблема с отделением содержимого сервиса у клиента. Мне бы только отправить ему интерфейс+контракты.

Заранее, огромное спасибо!

Comment: У вас WCF-службы? В вопросе ни разу это слово не мелькало и нет никаких явных указаний.

Comment: Судя по вашим вопросам на сайте, речь идёт о wcf. Добавил тег.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша структура приложения должна выглядеть примерно вот таким образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервисный контракт:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Contracts.DataContracts.TestContract;

namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Contracts.ServiceContracts
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        TestContractResult TestContract(TestContractRequest request);
    }
}
```

Клиент примерно так:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using log4net;
using MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Contracts.DataContracts.TestContract;
using MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Contracts.ServiceContracts;

namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Client
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public SomeClass(string bindingName)
        {
            this.BindingName = bindingName;
            this.WcfService = GetService();
            this.Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SomeClass).Name);
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            var answer = this.WcfService.TestContract(new TestContractRequest {MyProperty1 = 0, MyProperty2 = string.Empty});
            Console.WriteLine(answer.MyProperty1);
            Console.WriteLine(answer.MyProperty2);
        }

        private IService GetService()
        {
            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(this.BindingName);
            var service = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            return service;
        }

        private string BindingName { get; set; }
        private IService WcfService { get; set; }
        private ILog Log { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Настройки клиента в app.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8050/tinyurl" name="IWcfService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBindings" contract="MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Contracts.ServiceContracts.IService" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBindings" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="512000">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="5000000" />
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MEX">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Это то, что мне нужно!
Спасибо огромное!!
Как перенесу в проект, скажу результат, но всё же расстраивает, что азы серверного приложения не до конца понимаю :( Считал, что отделить интерфейс контракта нельзя отделить (как-то въелась мне эта мысль) и на этом застрял.